# Convert Jquery date to custom timezone by timezone id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to display datetime value on my real time page and i have done following jquery function for that.

```
 function DisplayTimer() {
            var x = new Date();
            $('#<%=lblTimer.ClientID %>').html(x.toString());
            setTimeout('DisplayTimer()', 5000);
        }
```

now i have **timezonid** value in my **session object** how can i convert above date value to custom timezone using timezonid session value and also want set **datetime format** as per **culture of user's browser** through this jquery function. I have solution in server side code so using [webmethod] i can do that it will make separate request for that every 5 second so i would like to do that without server side interaction. please help me if anyone done this type of logic.

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with:

```
var ClientDatetime = x.getMonth() + "/" + x.getDate() + "/"  + x.getYear() + " " 
+ x.getHours() + ":" + x.getMinutes() + ":" + x.getSeconds();
```

take one hidden variable hdnClientDateTime with runate = server and set value as following

```
hdnClientDateTime.value = ClientDatetime;
```

Now, Pass hdnClientDateTime.value variable in your server side Datetime format function and assign the value into label like this:

```
$('#<%=lblTimer.ClientID %>').html(Result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but If I'll take hiddenfield then value is not going to change as per requirements. it's require postback.